# What is the maximum number of overs allowed to bowl in a single day of a test match?

Tags: rules, cricket, officiating, icc

Minimum number of overs allowed per day in a test cricket match is 90.

What is the maximum number of overs allowed to bowl?

If 2 or 3 more overs required to win the match means, who will decide whether to extend the match or declare it as a draw?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no maximum number of overs allowed to be bowled in a Test match.  The extent of play is determined by time.

On the last day, the provisions for the "last hour" apply.  At least 15 overs need to be bowled after the last hour has started.  If a team is short of victory when the time is up and the 15 overs have been bowled, the match is a draw.

Comment: Also if it is not the last day and the result is very close, any team can request for extra half hour if lights (and other conditions) are okay. (so they don't need to wait for the next day!)

Comment: And this rule applied in this recent match between [India Vs Aus.](http://www.espncricinfo.com/india-v-australia-2013/engine/match/598814.html)